# Show a Button on ng-form change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have an `ng-form="step1"` which is populated with data from db.

When the user changes some thing in the input boxes or selects a different radio btn, I want to display a `Update Button`.

This button will be hidden at first.

How to do this?

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $dirty function of angularjs

example

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="update" ng-show="changedetect.$dirty" />
```